# Left join de PHPActiveRecord usando CodeIgniter não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou usando left join do PHPActiveRecord para obter dados de companhias e usuários, mas não está funcionando. Uso as tabelas users e companies como relacionamento da tabela proposals. Quero obter os dados dos usuários no foreach, mas não estou obtendo.

Classe model Proposal.php

```
<?php

class Proposal extends ActiveRecord\Model
{

    static $belongs_to = array(
       array('company'),
       array('user'),
    );

}
```

Classe controller proposals.php

```
public function index()
{
    $join = 'JOIN users u ON(proposals.vendedor_id = u.id)';
    $proposals = Proposal::all(array('joins' => $join));

    foreach ($proposals as $proposal) {
        echo 'vendedor_id -> ' . $proposal->vendedor_id .
             '<br>company -> ' . $proposal->company->name . 
             '<br>user -> ' . $proposal->user->username . '<br>';
    }

    exit();
}
```

Minha resposta é:

**vendedor_id -> 1,
company -> teste nova companhia,
user -> (não retorna dados de user)**

Gostaria de entender o motivo de não retornar os dados do usuário.

MER do meu banco MySQL:

[image: Tabela users]
[image: Tabela proposals]
[image: Tabela companies]

> Fonte: https://phpactiverecord.xyz/projects/main/wiki/Finders/

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt, recomendo conhecer nosso [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Ao criar perguntas no site, procure sempre escrever todas as informações na pergunta, evitando assim o uso de imagens. Deixe-as para casos extremamente específicos.

Comment: Escreva o código e a saída do mesmo na pergunta. Complementando sempre com [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Consegui chegar ao resultado esperado usando a function:

public function index()
    {
        $proposals = Proposal::find_by_sql('select p.*, u.firstname from proposals p INNER join users u on p.vendedor_id = u.id');

        foreach ($proposals as $proposal) {
            echo 'vendedor_id -> ' . $proposal->vendedor_id .
                 '<br>company -> ' . $proposal->company->name . 
                 '<br>user -> ' . $proposal->firstname . '<br>';
        }

        exit();
    }